# Win 10 > PowerShell creating a new user

Tags: windows-10, powershell

I am trying use powershell to create and remove users from a local computer. I am logged in as an admin in Win10 Home but when I run the command, which I am confident is correct, I am given a message that says "access is denied."

Any insight why I would not have the authority to run this script?

Comment: You may be logged in as admin,  but are you running PowerShell as admin?

Comment: "when I run the command" - What command.  Edit your question

Comment: If possible, you can take some screenshots to show what command you used, and what error you got.

Comment: @Scott got it. I was logged in as admin but was not running PowerShell as an admin. Shoot. Rookie mistake. Thanks for the insights everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please write the command ?

Maybe, write `-Verb runAs` at end of your command fix your problem.